# Найти первый идущий после определенного элемента , элемент

Tags: jquery, css3, html5

Есть блок

```
<li>
        <p class="arrow">▼</p>
        <a href="">Раздел 1</a>
                <ul class="thirdlvl">
                    <li><p class="point">.</p><a href="">Раздел 1.1</a></li>
                    <li><p class="point">.</p><a href="">Раздел 2.1</a</li> 
                    <li><p class="point">.</p><a href="">Раздел 3.1</a></li>
                    <li><p class="point">.</p><a href="">Раздел 4.1</a></li>
                    <li><p class="point">.</p><a href="">Раздел 5.1</a></li>
                    <li><p class="point">.</p><a href="">Раздел 6.1</a></li>
                    <li><p class="point">.</p><a href="">Раздел 7.1</a></li>
                    <li><p class="point">.</p><a href="">Раздел 8.1</a></li>
                    <li><p class="point">.</p><a href="">Раздел 9.1</a></li>
                </ul>
</li>
```

За ним идет еще один такой же, с `Разделом 2`

```
 <li>
            <p class="arrow">▼</p>
            <a href="">Раздел 2</a>
                    <ul class="thirdlvl">
                        <li><p class="point">.</p><a href="">Раздел 1.2</a></li>
                        <li><p class="point">.</p><a href="">Раздел 2.2</a</li> 
                        <li><p class="point">.</p><a href="">Раздел 3.2</a></li>
                        <li><p class="point">.</p><a href="">Раздел 4.2</a></li>
                        <li><p class="point">.</p><a href="">Раздел 5.2</a></li>
                        <li><p class="point">.</p><a href="">Раздел 6.2</a></li>
                        <li><p class="point">.</p><a href="">Раздел 7.2</a></li>
                        <li><p class="point">.</p><a href="">Раздел 8.2</a></li>
                        <li><p class="point">.</p><a href="">Раздел 9.2</a></li>
                    </ul>
    </li>
```

У класса thirdlvl

```
.thirdlvl {display:none;}
```

Я хочу при клике на `<p class="arrow">` разворачивать `thirdlvl` того раздела которому он принадлежит. Как зацепить этот селектор? (`thirdlvl`, того же раздела что и `arrow`)?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.arrow').on('click', function(){
   var thirdlvl = $(this).parent().find('.thirdlvl');

   thirdlvl.show();
});
```

Ну как вариант, отслеживаем клик по `arrow`, берем его родителя и ищем в нем элемент с классом `thirdlvl`